# How to send data from Android activity to reactNative Android bridge module

Tags: android, react-native

I've integrated stripe android SDK in my react native application for payments. The flow is like

1. react native button calls native module (js bridge) and that module
   opens up an android activity for payment page
2. that collects the card information and returns the payment result id from backend API whether payment is success or not
3. I want to send that id from Android activity to native module so that I can fetch that data from react native

Comment: Hi! Did you try this https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#sending-events-to-javascript?

Comment: No, in this activity must be extended from ReactActivity, in my case its pure native activity, which extends AppcompatActivity

Comment: Ok, then use startActivityForResult.

Comment: same thing mate, startActivityForResult works with AppCompatActivity not with native module or reactActivity

Comment: There are enough APIs to implement what you need. Check this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult